# When reusing character array I always get extra letter of previous value in the end

Tags: arrays, c

I am toying around with C language and I wanted to see how exactly null character `\0` works. I have a character array initialized to length of 1000. I read text stream with `getchar` and place the characters into the array by iterating over the whole length of the array (1000).
After the loop I add null character to the end of stored characters. After this, I repeat the exact thing for second time. However when I print out the characters for 2nd time, I always get extra letter in the output.

1. STDIN input: `aa`
2. output `aa`
3. STDIN input `b`
4. output `ba` (I would expect it to be just `b`)

This is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000

int main() {
  char line[MAX];

  int i;
  int c;
  for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < MAX - 1; ++i) {
    line[i] = c;
  }

  ++i;
  line[i] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", line);

  for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < MAX - 1; ++i) {
    line[i] = c;
  }

  ++i;
  line[i] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing `0` one character too far.

`for` loop advanced the last char (to be populated in a loop). the `line[i]` is where that `0` should go. Remove `++i`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using pre-increment and i value get increased, Just remove ++i before assigning '\0'
Try this:

```
#define MAX 1000

int main() {
  char line[MAX];

  int i;
  int c;
  for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < MAX - 1; ++i) {
    line[i] = c;
  }

  line[i] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", line);

  for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < MAX - 1; ++i) {
    line[i] = c;
  }

  line[i] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you end a for loop as the ones you have written, you must think that `i` gets incremented just before the test that makes you to get out of the loop, so `i` actually points to the next character position.

This makes your lines

```
    ++i;
```

unnecessary, and you should just say:

```
    line[i] = '\0';
```